# Can I setup MaaS/Juju and OpenStack completely offline?

Tags: juju, maas

I am trying to setup Openstack using the Ubuntu Cloud recommended way with MAAS + JUJU. I have some basic questions as I am very new to MAAS Setup.

Can the MAAS Environment(including the minimal OS images),JUJU bootstrap & charms setup be made completely offline without the need to fetch the packages from the internet every time we need to reinstall(Download & reuse next time). I have seen some way to do this for the bootstrap image & charms for juju but can we completely avoid going to the ubuntu repos everytime the setup is done?

Comment: Off the top of my head this sounds like a case for debpartial-mirror being used to create a local mirror for sources.list.  I would really defer to somebody else on this, though.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible.